# ExtJS drag/drop a CompositeSprite

Tags: javascript, graphics, extjs, extjs4, sprite

I want to set draggable on a CompositeSprite using Ext JS 4.0. There are examples on how I can set draggable a single sprite (draggable: true), but it doesn't work for CompositeSprite. If I write:

```js
compositeSprite.setAttributes({
  draggable: true
});
```

the result is each sprite in compositeSprite can be dragged separately. I need them to be dragged together.

I have also tried to use dd property which contains Ext.dd.DragSource, but I can't apply Ext.dd.DragSource to Sprites. (There are no examples on the net, only for grid and tree).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Wrap 'em all up in a draggable div?

Comment: @Reanimation I suppose I can't wrap sprites into div.

Comment: @Reanimation For example I have div. I can only render drawComponent to div, not sprites (because they dont inherit Ext.Component).

Comment: Thanks, draggable div is the solution.